# Click OK button within alert window in an embedded hellosign region using Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to click the 'Ok' button inside an alert window with a Selenium command. The alert window comes from a hellosign.com page which is embedded in the html page. Please find the html snippet and the options that I have tried below. The page is designed in angular js.

## HTML

`<div class="m-signature-request-preview--test-warning--content"><h3>This is not legally binding</h3><p>This is a mock signature request and has no legal value.</p><button class="m-button bg-cerulean  hc-white border-1-cerulean hborder-1-cerulean hbg-cerulean c-white progress-button state-loading" type="button" tabindex="0"><span class="l-nowrap">OK</span></button></div>`

Here are the details of the button:

### Selector :

`#signer-mobile-application > div > div > div > div.m-signature-request-preview--test-warning > div.m-signature-request-preview--test-warning--content > button > span`

### XPath :

`//*[@id="signer-mobile-application"]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/button/span`

### JS Path :

`document.querySelector("#signer-mobile-application > div > div > div > div.m-signature-request-preview--test-warning > div.m-signature-request-preview--test-warning--content > button > span")`

CSS class of the button is m-button

[image]

While the page I'm trying to automate is not accessible to public, the flow is almost similar to the samples given on hellosign.com website given below. Unfortunately the popup is not shown in the steps below , but you can view the embedded hellosign.com page to understand the nature of UI.

1. Click https://app.hellosign.com/api/embeddedTest
2. Click "Get A Sample Document"
3. Click "Launch Embedded Page"
4. Click on the popup ( Already automated )
5. UI should show Hello Sign Agreement
6. The popup in the image above is shown at this stage.
7. Scroll down till you see click to sign.
8. Click on the click to sign region.
9. In Create Signature page, click "Type it In"
10. Click Insert.

In my application I get a popup after step 5, which is not shown in the steps above. After clicking the popup I need to automate all the steps till step 9 above. Anything inside hellosign region is not getting identified, which is step 7, 8 above.There is no way for me to find out the x and y coordinates of the embedded region and leverage Robot() class to click that button. The browser shows the coordinates around the page but not inside the page.Looks like its not an embedded iframe , but an external source embedded in an angular js page.

### I've tried the following 23 alternatives individually

1) `Alert alert = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
   driver.switchTo().alert().accept();` causes 
     org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException: no such alert

2) `JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
   js.executeScript("document.querySelector('.m-button.bg- 
   cerulean').click()");`

3) `js.executeScript("document.querySelector('.m-button 
   .bg- cerulean').click()");`

4) `js.executeScript("document.querySelector('.m-button.bg-
    cerulean.hc-white.border-1-cerulean.hborder-1-cerulean.hbg- 
    cerulean.c-white.progress-button.state-loading').click()");`

5) `try{
     while(true) {
         new WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
         .ignoring(ElementNotVisibleException.class, 
         NoSuchElementException.class)

         .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(
         By.cssSelector("button[title*='OK']")))).click();
      }
   } catch (Exception ignored){ }`

6)  `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(
    "button[title*='OK']")).click();`

7)  `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("//button/span[title*='OK']"))
    .click();`

8)  `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("//button/span[@title,'OK']"))
    .click();`

9)  `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("l-nowrap")).click();`

10) `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button/span[contains
    (@class,'l-nowrap')]")).click();`

11) `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button/span[
    @class,'l-nowrap']")).click();`

12) `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[
    @class,'l-nowrap']")).click();`

13) `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button/span[@title,'OK']"))
    .click();`

14) `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@title,'OK']")).click();`

15) `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(@title,'OK')]"))
    .click();`

16) `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("m-button")).click();`

17) `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button/span[contains(
    @class,'m-button')]")).click();`

18) `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[
    @class,'m-button']")).click();`

19) `driver.findElement(By.xpath(
    "//*[@id=\"signer-mobile- 
    application\"]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/button[title*='OK']"))
    .click();`

20) `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[
    @id=\"signer-mobile- 
    application\"]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/button[@title,'OK']"))
   .click();`

21) `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"signer-mobile- 
     application\"]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/button/span
     [@title,'OK']"))
     .click();`

22) `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"signer-mobile- 
    application\"]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/button/span
    [@class,'l-nowrap']")).click();`

23) `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("//*[@id=\"signer-mobile- 
    application\"]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/button[@title,'OK']"))
    .click();`

Comment: How to show the alert `Ok` button?

Comment: manual step to reach that alert button? Check if there any `iframe` available?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Updated the manual steps in the problem statement above.

Comment: I followed the manual steps you posted and I'm not seeing an OK button. Please document each and every step you are following and indicate clearly where the OK button is. Please don't document 10 steps when it fails at 5. Stop at 5 and make it clear what the issue is. A screenshot here would probably really help.

Comment: Thanks JeffC. The Ok button is shown in our application which is not publicly accessible. It's part of the embedded hellosign.com page embedded in the html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved.

The OK popup is shown only for trial version of hellosign.com page and not with the licence version. Thats why the manual steps above did not show it.

While the button could not be identified, the popup disappears after clicking two tab buttons. So this worked.

`Actions action = new Actions(driver);       action.sendKeys(Keys.TAB).build().perform();
action.sendKeys(Keys.TAB).build().perform();
Thread.sleep(5000);`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be going for [XPath Selector](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#dfn-xpath-selector) and [normalize-space()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space) function like:

```
//button[normalize-space()='OK']
```

Demo:

[image]

References:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XPath Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Appreciate it a lot. The following exception is thrown when I execute the code :Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[normalize-space()='OK']"}
  (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.132)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html . The popup is shown in an hellosign page which is embedded within the html page.

Answer (score 0):

Use `WebDriverWait` and `elementToBeClickable` and following locator strategy.

**xpath**:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement elementBtn = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[contains(@class,'progress-button')]/span[text()='OK']")));
elementBtn.click();
```

**CssSelector**:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement elementBtn = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button.progress-button span.l-nowrap")));
elementBtn.click();
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately it's not working.  :-(                                     
 Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[contains(@class,'progress-button')]/span[text()='OK']"}
Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"button.progress-button span.l-nowrap"}

Comment: @user3274631 : You have mentioned in you steps fill all the fields in page1.What is your page1?Can you share the link?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Appreciate it. 
While the page is not accessible to public , its almost similar to the samples given on hellosign.com website. Please check the flow below : 
`1. Click https://app.hellosign.com/api/embeddedTest 
2. Click "Get A Sample Document" 
3. Click "Launch Embedded Page" 
4. Click on the popup ( Already automated )  
5. UI should show Hello Sign Agreement 
6. Scroll down till you see click to sign. 
7. Click on the click to sign region. 
8. In Create Signature page, click "Type it In"
9. Click Insert.`

Comment: seems like the click should go to the button... so something like this, "//button[contains(@class,'m-button')]", instead.

Comment: So are you able to click or Not?

Answer (score 0):

```
String frame2 = "";

List<WebElement> iframes = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));   
for(int i = 0; i < iframes.size(); i++) {
String frameName = iframes.get(i).getAttribute("name");
System.out.println("attributes name "+ frameName);
frame1 = iframes.get(0).getAttribute("name");
frame2 = iframes.get(1).getAttribute("name");
}

System.out.println("frame 1 " + frame1);

System.out.println("frame 2 " + frame2);

driver.switchTo().defaultContent();


WebElement frameFirst = driver.findElement(By.name(frame1));

driver.switchTo().frame(frameFirst);

driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

WebElement frameSecond = driver.findElement(By.name(frame2));
driver.switchTo().frame(frameSecond);
Thread.sleep(8000);

//Clicks on Ok

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'l-nowrap') and contains(text(), 'OK')]")).click();

System.out.println("Clicked on Ok");

Thread.sleep(8000);
```

Comment: Please read [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and update your answer with recommendations.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes